# How can I split a row into two or more rows with single key in the column as depicted in the image using React-Table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

[image]

Is there a way to split a row into multiple rows as given in the image for a single column key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
<Row>
 {index === 0 ? (
   <Cell
       rowSpan={rows.length}
       style={{ padding: '8px' }}>
        B
   </Cell>
  ) : null}
  <Cell
      style={{ padding: '8px' }}>
       {row.cells[1].render('Cell')}
  </Cell>
  <Cell
      style={{ padding: '8px' }}>
       {row.cells[2].render('Cell')}
  </Cell>
  <Cell
      style={{ padding: '8px' }}>
       {row.cells[3].render('Cell')}
  </Cell>
</Row>
```

[Rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) attribute specifies the number of rows a cell should span.
And [there](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-wildflower-kwxo1) you can find my code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just looking for the Rowspan attribute, I got it.

Comment: @thevatsalsaglani you can approve answer ;)